# How to create an array consisting of the tokens created using the strtok function?

Tags: c, arrays, ini, strtok

I am new with .ini files and thus this qn(which might seem silly) .I have created a .ini file and access it via my C program. The ini file looks like this:

```
 [key]
 title = A,H,D
```

The C program accesses it using:

```
 LPCSTR ini ="C:\\conf.ini;
 char var[100];
 GetPrivateProfileString("key", "title", 0, var, 100, ini);

 printf("%s", var);
 char* buffer = strtok(var, ", ");
do{
    printf("%s", buffer);

    if (strcmp(buffer, "A")==0)
        printf("Hello");

    puts("");
}while ((buffer=strtok(NULL, ", "))!= NULL);
```

output looks as :

```
  A H D F G IAHello
  H
  D
  F
  G
```

Now what I need to do is use these individual tokens again to form an array with indices within my C program. For example:

```
  char x[A, H, D, F, G]
```

so that when I refer to the index 2, x[2] should give me 'D'. Could somebody suggest a way to do this. I have never used strtok before and thus very confused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `returnValue2` contain ?, Is this code complete ?

Comment: you can use a pointer array to hold all the strings returned by `strtok`

Comment: @SaurabhMeshram:Sorry for the confusion. I eited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite similar to others regarding getting external information and storing it in an array.

**The problem** here is the amount of elements in your array to store.

You could use Link-lists, but for this example, I would scan the file, getting the total amount of items needed for the array - and then parse the file data again - storing the items in the array.

The first loop, goes through and counts the items to be store, as per your example posted. I will do the second loop just as an example - please note in my example you would of created nTotalItems and have counted the amount of items, storing that in nTotalItems ... I am assuming you want to store a string, not just a char...

Also please note this a draft example, done at work - only to show a method of storing the tokens into an array, therefore there is no error checking ec

```
 // nTotalItems has already been calculated via the first loop...
 char** strArray = malloc( nTotalItems * sizeof( char* ));
 int    nIndex  = 0;

 // re-setup buffer
 buffer = strtok(var, ", ");
 do {

     // allocate the buffer for string and copy...    
     strArray[ nIndex ] = malloc( strlen( buffer ) + 1 );
     strcpy( strArray[ nIndex ], buffer );

     printf( "Array %d = '%s'\n", nIndex, strArray[ nIndex ] );

     nIndex++;

 } while ((buffer=strtok(NULL, ", "))!= NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [an INI parser that supports arrays](https://github.com/madmurphy/libconfini).

INI file:

```
[my_section]
title = A,H,D
```

C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <confini.h>

#define MY_ARRAY_DELIMITER ','

struct configuration {
    char ** title;
    size_t title_length;
};

static char ** make_strarray (size_t * arrlen, const char * src, const size_t buffsize, IniFormat ini_format) {

    *arrlen = ini_array_get_length(src, MY_ARRAY_DELIMITER, ini_format);
    char ** const dest = *arrlen ? (char **) malloc(*arrlen * sizeof(char *) + buffsize) : NULL;
    if (!dest) { return NULL; }
    memcpy(dest + *arrlen, src, buffsize);
    char * iter = (char *) (dest + *arrlen);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < *arrlen; idx++) {
        dest[idx] = ini_array_release(&iter, MY_ARRAY_DELIMITER, ini_format);
        ini_string_parse(dest[idx], ini_format);
    }

    return dest;

}

static int ini_handler (IniDispatch * this, void * v_conf) {

    struct configuration * conf = (struct configuration *) v_conf;

    if (this->type == INI_KEY && ini_string_match_si("my_section", this->append_to, this->format)) {

        if (ini_string_match_si("title", this->data, this->format)) {

            /*  Save memory (not strictly needed)  */
            this->v_len = ini_array_collapse(this->value, MY_ARRAY_DELIMITER, this->format);

            /*  Allocate a new array of strings  */
            if (conf->title) { free(conf->title); }
            conf->title = make_strarray(&conf->title_length, this->value, this->v_len + 1, this->format);
            if (!conf->title) { return 1; }

        }

    }

    return 0;

}

static int conf_init (IniStatistics * statistics, void * v_conf) {

    *((struct configuration *) v_conf) = (struct configuration) { NULL, 0 };
    return 0;

}

int main () {

    struct configuration my_conf;

    /*  Parse the INI file  */
    if (load_ini_path("C:\\conf.ini", INI_DEFAULT_FORMAT, conf_init, ini_handler, &my_conf)) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, something went wrong :-(\n");
        return 1;

    }

    /*  Print the parsed data  */
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < my_conf.title_length; idx++) {

        printf("my_conf.title[%d] = %s\n", idx, my_conf.title[idx]);

    }

    /*  Free the parsed data  */
    if (my_conf.title_length) {

        free(my_conf.title);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
my_conf.title[0] = A
my_conf.title[1] = H
my_conf.title[2] = D
```